# Extending a factory

Tags: design-patterns, dart

I have two classes

```dart
class A {
    String _id;

    static final Map<String, A> _instances = <String, A>{};

    factory A.getInstance(String id){            
        if(!_instances.containsKey(id)){
            _instances[id] = new A._internal(id);
        }
        return _instances[id];            
    }    

    A._internal(this._id);
}

class B extends A {
    factory B.getInstance(int id){
        return new A.getInstance(id.toString());
    }
}
```

I know that this isn't good practice since class A is not a subtype of class B. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *implement* `A` and delegate method calls either by implementing all methods or using `noSuchMethod(invocation)`.

For a given `A` class :

```dart
class A {
  static final Map<String, A> _instances = <String, A>{};

  String _id;

  A._internal(this._id);
  factory A.getInstance(String id) =>
      _instances.putIfAbsent(id, () => new A._internal(id));

  String get id => _id;
  String get name => "name_${_id}";
}
```

Your `B` class could look like :

```dart
class B implements A {
  final A a;

  B(int id) : a = new A.getInstance(id.toString());

  String get id => a.id;
  String get name => a.name;
}
```

or with `noSuchMethod` :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
class B implements A {
  final A a;

  B(int id) : a = new A.getInstance(id.toString());

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => reflect(a).delegate(invocation);
}
```